# Should we normalize / standardize / feature-scale a categorical variable?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, feature-scaling

variable - **'Item_Fat_Content'**
values - **'Low Fat', 'Regular', 'High fat', 'No fat'**

These values on converting into label will take values of 0,1,2,3. On standardising, they will take up numerical values  something like 0.0,0.4,0.5,0.9.

Will python consider this  'Item_Fat_Content' as categorical or numerical variable while applying algorithms?

Comment: It will consider as numerical variable. But I think you shouldn't use 0,1,2,3 but create four columns where you use binary values (f.e  (Low Fat, Regular, High Fat, No fat) (0,0,0,1),(1,0,0,0) etc...) Because alghoritm might determine that "No Fat" has higher weight on result than "Low fat".

Comment: And the question is should you standardize binary variables? Here's a thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59392/should-you-ever-standardise-binary-variables

Comment: try using One Hot Encoding as @OlegMusijenko said. You can use get_dummies in pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)